# $\operatorname{im}(T)+\ker (T)$ where $\operatorname{im}(T) \subset \mathbb R _3 [x]$ and $\ker (T) \subset M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have this question:

Given a linear transformation $\textsf T: \textsf{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R_3 [x]$ defined by 
$$\textsf T\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix} = (a-d)x^2 +(b+c)x+(5a-5d)$$ 
for any $\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix} \in \textsf{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$.
$$\ker (\textsf T)=\operatorname{span}\left( \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1 \\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}\right\} \right)$$
$$\operatorname{im}(\textsf T)=\operatorname{span}( \{x^2+5, x\})$$

- Is it true that $\textsf{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R) = \ker (\textsf T)+\operatorname{im}(\textsf T)$?
- Is it true that $\textsf{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)=\ker (\textsf T) \oplus \operatorname{im}(\textsf T)$?

My answer for both questions is that $a+b$ is not defined when $a\in \textsf{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ and $\:b\in \mathbb R_3[x]$.

Would that be enough for an answer? Maybe I'm totally wrong and the addition is defined  somehow?

Comment: A could accept a "-1" for the question with a comment...

Comment: Given that (as you have noted) you can't add an element of $KerT$ to an element of $ImT$, what do you mean by $KerT+ImT$ in the first place?

Comment: I was typing my comment while you were typing yours.  It really is quite impossible to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @WillO I really don't mean anything... That is the actual question I've got in my homework. It seems really awkward so I've decided to ask the community.

Comment: I could post a question asking "Does $y=7$?".  If someone responds "Huh?  What's $y$?", I could respond "I have no idea."  If that ever happens, I hope I'll get a downvote.

Comment: @WillO your analogy is incorrect.  It is either you didn't read the question or don't understand English. I said that this is the question I've got and the question itself seems to me like "is it true that bicycle = yellow + tomorrow". Because I'm not a math expert, I suggested the question is irrelevant, but asked here to maybe find I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right!

A linear map $\textsf T$ that goes from a vector space $\textsf V$ to itself is called a *linear operator*. Only in that case it makes sense to talk about subspaces such as $\ker (\textsf T)+\operatorname{im}(\textsf T)$ or $\ker (\textsf T) \cap \operatorname{im}(\textsf T)$.